# python2.5 packages in virtualenv contain too new syntax for python2.5

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, python-2.5

I've created a virtualenv that uses python2.5 instead of my default version python2.6 by executing this command:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.5 myvirtualenv --no-site-packages
```

Now, when I want to install packages in the virtualenv using pip, I get syntax errors like this one:

```
File "/home/philipp/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.5.egg/pip/vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 276
    return b''
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That means that my python2.5 packages contain syntax that is not yet valid in python2.5. When I use `pip-2.5` this will not change anything. There should be two possibilities to get around this problem:

1. Somehow tell pip that it should accept the newer syntax
2. Find the misconfiguration of the virtualenv program and repair it.

I'm happy about any ideas about how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pip version 1.4 requires Python 2.6 or newer.

You'll need to install Pip version 1.3.1 if you want it to work on Python 2.5, see [Python & OS Support](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#python-os-support).

Comment: And more specifically, you must use virtualenv 1.9.1 to get pip 1.3.1 (virtualenv 1.10 upgraded to pip 1.4 and dropped support for python 2.5).  Many packages have recently dropped support for python 2.5, so you'll need to stay on older versions of those packages if you need keep using 2.5.

Comment: And even more specifically, I also had to downgrade setuptools to 1.4.2 and to use virtualenv with the option --extra-search-dir in order to use my downgraded setuptools version instead of downloading the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

pip versions 1.4.1+ no longer support Python 2.5. I recommend you install an older version of pip (1.3.1 will do) or use a more recent version of Python2 (2.6 will do).

Source: 
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html